# change div class name if other div is empty

Tags: jquery

Hi hope someone can help out with this one:

What I basically want is that when div introtext is empty it has to hide the div and change the parent div (grid-6) to class=grid-12. I can't seem to get this job done! Here's what I have (samplecode):

> **HTML**

```
<div class=header>
    <img src="[[DTIMAGE]]" alt="inuit.css logo">
</div>
<h1 style="font-size:10px;">[[TITLE]]</h1>
<div class=grids>
    <div class=grid-12>
        [[FULLTEXT]]
    </div><!-- /grid-6 -->
</div><!-- /grids -->
<hr>
<div class=grids>
    <div class=grid-6>
        [[FULLTEXT]]
    </div><!-- /grid-6 -->
    <div class=grid-6>
        <div class="introtext"></div>
    </div><!-- /grid-6 -->
</div><!-- /grids -->
<hr>
<div class=footer>
    [[FOOTER]]
</div>
```

> **Script** [*using jQuery 1.7.2*]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(".introtext").text() === ""){
        $(".introtext").hide();
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then I'd suggest:

```
$('.introtext').each(
    function() {
        if (!$(this).text()) {
            $(this).hide().parent().toggleClass('grid-6 grid-12');
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/P45cU/).

The above code reworked to account for changes to the requirements, as noted in the comment from the OP:

> I'm totally wrong (too much digging to get this to work) The fact is that if div introtext is empty the div grid-6 (where the [[FULLTEXT]] is in ) should change to div=grid-12

```
$('.introtext').each(
    function() {
        if (!$(this).text()) {
            $(this).hide().parent().prev().toggleClass('grid-6 grid-12');
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/P45cU/1/).

Reprised the above:

```
$('.grid-6').filter(
    function(){
        var introtextEl = $(this).next('.grid-6').find('.introtext');
        return introtextEl.length && !introtextEl.text()
    }).toggleClass('grid-6 grid-12');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/P45cU/3/).

The above code (the latest code block), effectively looks at *all* the elements returned by the selector, and filters them based on two conditions, first: if there is a following element of class `grid-6` with a child element of class `introtext` (jQuery selectors always return an array, hence the `.length` check), and second: if that found `.introtext` element has no text-content.

If these conditions are both true then the currently-assessed element (and all elements for which the conditions are true) are returned to be acted upon by the `toggleClass()` method.

References:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: David, thanks for the answer. When I use this is see no changes BUT..... I'm totally wrong (too much digging to get this to work)

The fact is that if div introtext is empty the div grid-6 (where the [[FULLTEXT]] is in ) should change to div=grid-12

Can you still follow?

Comment: Check the edit, the second code block should achieve your aims, I think? The JS Fiddle seems to support that claim, at least. =)

Comment: David, thanks for your help. Almost there! I need the specific div (grid-6) where the [[FULLTEXT]] is in to change to grid-12 and not all. Should I give every div, where class=grid-6) a different id and do something with that?

Comment: What uniquely identifies the div where `[[FULLTEXT]]` is found? Does it have an `id`? A unique combination of `class` names? Some `data-*`, or other, attribute? Is there only *one* `.introtext` element?

Comment: David, at this point there is no unique identiefier. I could add id=fulltext at the div where the [[FULLTEXT]] is to make it unique. The text [[FULLTEXT]] is dynamicly inserted content. What if that div had: id=fulltext ?

Comment: That would certainly make it easier to select.

Comment: IF I did how would I accomplish my goal? any suggestions on that one?

Comment: Wow David, you're awesome. This does the job but I'm not sure HOW it does the job!! But for future references: if I use a unique id with a div -- how would the code be: If div class='x' = empty than change div class='y' with an id of 'z' to div class=something ? You're a great help and I can't thank you enough for helping me out. I'm just learning.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)** selector:

```
if ( $(".introtext").is(':empty') ){
      $(".introtext").hide().parent().attr('class', 'grid-12')
}
```

If you have more than one element with class of `introtext` you can use the `each` method:

```
$('.introtext').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(':empty') ){
          $(this).hide().parent().attr('class', 'grid-12')
    }
})
```

---

```
$('.girds div').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).text() == '[[FULLTEXT]]'){
          $(this).attr('class', 'grid-12')
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi Raminson, thanks for your comment (and possible solution) but I need the div with the [[FULLTEXT]] to change to grid-12. Any Idea for this one (so not for the parent div)?

Comment: @user1264351 Hi, you are welcome, something like the updated answer?

Comment: Thanks we're almost there. The text [[FULLTEXT]] is dynamicly inserted content so we cant search for that text. Besides that if the div introtext is empty only the fulltext div (class=grid-6) should change to class=grid-12 So what is basically does is that I have two columns (1 with fulltext and one with intro text). If there is no intro text the full text should expand (so I have only 1 column). Hope this explains it better.